# use facebook sdk in fragment

Tags: android, facebook, android-fragments

I need facebook login in my app, so for that i am using the `facebook sdk v4.7.0`.Previous i have used this sdk but in activity, but now i want to use in fragment.I tried but the facebook login webview dialog is not opening.

Code

```
@Override

    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

        callbackManager = CallbackManager.Factory.create();


 LoginManager.getInstance().logInWithReadPermissions(this, Arrays.asList("public_profile,email"));
        LoginManager.getInstance().registerCallback(callbackManager, new FacebookCallback<LoginResult>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(LoginResult loginResult) {

                GraphRequest.newMeRequest(
                        loginResult.getAccessToken(), new GraphRequest.GraphJSONObjectCallback() {
                            @Override
                            public void onCompleted(JSONObject json, GraphResponse response) {
                                if (response.getError() != null) {
                                    // handle error
                                    System.out.println("ERROR");
                                } else {
                                    System.out.println("Success");
                                    try {

                                        String jsonresult = String.valueOf(json);
                                        System.out.println("JSON Result" + jsonresult);

                                        String str_email = json.getString("email");
                                        String str_id = json.getString("id");
                                        String str_firstname = json.getString("first_name");
                                        String str_lastname = json.getString("last_name");

                                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                                        e.printStackTrace();
                                    }
                                }
                            }

                        }).executeAsync();

            }

            @Override
            public void onCancel() {

            }

            @Override
            public void onError(FacebookException error) {

            }
        });
    }
    }
```

OnActivityResult

```
@Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        callbackManager.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);


    }
```

Manifest

```
<application>

<activity
            android:name="com.facebook.FacebookActivity"
            android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|screenLayout|screenSize|orientation"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar" />

        <meta-data
            android:name="com.facebook.sdk.ApplicationId"
            android:value="@string/fb_id" />
</application
```

Comment: But , why you wanted to work on Fragment ?

Comment: bcos tats the requirement sir

Comment: I would try testing this on the latest SDK with one of the sample projects bundled with the SDK (like rps or Scrumptious) since this will give you some pointers